# Having trouble with the Colorgram library in Python

Tags: python, image, colors

I am using Python's colorgram library to extract color information from an image. One version of my code is as follows:

```
import colorgram

num_cols = 25

rgb_colors = []
colors = colorgram.extract('image.jpg', num_cols)
for color in colors:
    r = color.rgb.r
    g = color.rgb.g
    b = color.rgb.b
    new_color = (r, g, b)
    rgb_colors.append(new_color)

print(rgb_colors)
print(len(rgb_colors))
```

The code works just fine, but if I give 'num_cols' a value of more than 36, the code only finds a maximum of 36 colors. I have tried different hi res images, and have tried different versions of the same code that I found online, but I always get this same limit of 36 colors; I just don't know where the problem can be, and I have not seen anyone else report the same issue. Can someone please tell me if I am doing something stupid here? Thanks.